# how to assign a struct in .NET C# to an MWStructArray in Matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab

I am trying to assign a struct defined in C# to an MWStructArray in MATLAB. I have declared a struct in the namespace:
    `public struct file
    {
        char[] name;
        char[] folder;
        double bytes;
    };`

and a routine inside a class of the same namespace is taking an argument to type file and trying to pass it to MWStructArray:

```
namespace X {
     class car {
          public double[,] car_service (file filename) {
              MWStructArray fileArr = file;
          }
      }

      public struct file
      {
          char[] name;
          char[] folder;
          double bytes;
      };
 }
```

the above is failing with error CS0029:
Cannot implicitly convert type X.file to Mathworks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.MWStructArray.

I also tried:
     `file [,] f = new file[1, 1];
      f [0, 0] = filename;
      MWStructArray fileArr = file;`

ands that also failing with same error code.

Comment: In c# char/string are class objects in c#  so you need to convert to a byte[] array.

Comment: can you show a solution or some code ? does the file need to converted to a byte [] array?

Comment: You can use lpstr in the dllimport statement and in the structure declare in struct as string (instead of char).  In c# a char is a class with one or two bytes while in Matlab it is one byte.  String in Matalb are one byte terminated with '\0'.  Putting lpstr wile automatically convert the matlab string (one byte terminated with '\0') to a c# string.  See following example (uses lpwstr which is a unicode two byte string.  The w is wide) : http://thelazydev.net/65_/using-c-c-within-c-part-2-writing-and-using-a-dll/